# mysql WHERE MATCH AGAINST

Tags: mysql, match, where-clause, against

I am having a problem with a mysql and MATCH AGANIST.

I got this row in my database :

```
1:{Czy jesteśmy tutaj sami};2:{Margit Sanoemo}
```

I want to find this by following query :

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE MATCH (params) AGAINST('*argi*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

but I got an empty row.

However with this query :

```
SELECT * FROM dataWHERE MATCH (params) AGAINST('margi*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get want  I want.

Can you help me with double ** in params ?  `AGAINST('*argi*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: I think you want to use is % instead of *

Comment: already tried, %% doesn`t work in MATCH AGANIST

Comment: and what about the 'like'?, can you use it?

Comment: did you try: SELECT * FROM data WHERE params like '%margi%'; ????, if that doesn't work you have problems with your code

Comment: I have to use MATCH AGANIST, because it is needed for my project.

Comment: `*` is only for appending not prepending. read my post below.

Answer (score 5):

`+`

A leading plus sign indicates that this word must be present
in every row returned.

`-`

A leading minus sign indicates that this word must not be
present in any row returned.

`< >`

These two operators are used to change a word’s contribution
to the relevance value that is assigned to a row. The < operator decreases
the contribution and the > operator increases it. See the example below.

`( )`

. Parentheses are put round sub-expressions to give them
higher precedence in the search.

`~`

A leading tilde acts as a negation operator, causing the
word’s contribution to the row relevance to be negative. It’s useful for marking
noise words. A row that contains such a word will be rated lower than others,
but will not be excluded altogether, as it would be with the minus
operator.

`*`

***An asterisk is the truncation operator. Unlike the other
operators, it is appended to the word, or fragment, not *prepended*.***

`“`

Double quotes at the beginning and end of a phrase, matches
only rows that contain the complete phrase, as it was typed.

Answer (score 0):

Do not embed variables into double-quoted strings and you are set:

`SELECT * FROM " . $table .` `WHERE MATCH (message) 
    AGAINST ('%" . $string . "%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`