# MySQL Match Against In Boolean Mode returns nothing on middle word

Tags: mysql, sql, match-against

I've got a problem using Match Against in my MySQL database, and I'm hoping someone can help.

This is the examples of the data in my database:

```
id   name
1    really bitter chocolate
2    soft cheese
```

When I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM food WHERE (name) LIKE "%bitter%"
```

This bring back the first result:

```
1    really bitter chocolate
```

However its part of a much larger query, and when I run the Match Against code, I don't get anything returned from either of these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM food WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("bitter")

SELECT * FROM food WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("bitter", IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I have full text searches turned on, and it works when I search the start of the name:

```
SELECT * FROM food WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("really")

SELECT * FROM food WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("really", IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Both of which returns:

```
1    really bitter chocolate
```

I've read through this for solutions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

And I've looked here: [mysql WHERE MATCH AGAINST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931701/mysql-where-match-against/10931978#10931978)

Can someone please see where I am going wrong or point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Ok as per Woot4Moo great answer below I've changed my code to remove the comma which shouldn't have been there. I've also added in the + and putting it in single quotes but still no luck.

My current query now looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM food WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+bitter' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But it's returning no results in query browser, and not returning any errors or warnings.

Comment: i updated my answer to point out the differences in your query vice mine.

Comment: do you get an error now or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM food WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("bitter", IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

looks like it should be:

```
SELECT * FROM food WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+bitter' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

notice how mine has the **plus sign** `+` and **NO comma** `,`

Basing it off of the example [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

> MySQL can perform boolean full-text searches using the IN BOOLEAN
>   MODE modifier. With this modifier, certain characters have special
>   meaning at the beginning or end of words in the search string. In the
>   following query, the + and - operators indicate that a word is
>   required to be present or absent, respectively, for a match to occur.
>   Thus, the query retrieves all the rows that contain the word “MySQL”
>   but that do not contain the word “YourSQL”:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
    -> AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Thanks I totally missed the comma, but it's still not working for me unfortunately :(

Comment: @hollie3406 can you try the single quote?  I know that shouldn't matter, but for the sake of completeness :)

Comment: No problem at all - my query now looks like this: 
    SELECT * FROM food WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+bitter' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

But it's still returning as empty :(

Answer (score 5):

If this are the only two rows in your table then you have in 50% of the records the searched string and it will be ignored.