# MATCH AGAINST Mysql not giving correct results

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, match

I am running a SQL Query as follows:

```
SELECT a.id as id,a.name as name , a.price as price , a.saleprice as saleprice, a.images as images, a.slug as slug,a.hover_name as hover_name, MATCH (a.name) AGAINST ('+"blue cushion"') AS title_relevance FROM gc_products a WHERE ( ( ( MATCH (a.name) AGAINST ('+"blue cushion"') ) OR (a.sku like '%blue cushion%') ) and (a.enabled=1) ) ORDER BY title_relevance DESC
```

But It is giving me wrong results it is also showing me records where name is like "blue candle" , "red cushion"

I have also tried

```
         MATCH (a.name) AGAINST ('blue cushion')

     MATCH (a.name) AGAINST ('+blue cushion')

MATCH (a.name) AGAINST ('+blue +cushion')
```

It's not necessary that both the words be together.They can be any where in name but it is necessary that both the words must be there in name. '+' sign means 0 or more while I need at least one time.

But same result coming. I want if there are more than one words to match then it should match all the words in name.

```
 MATCH (a.name) AGAINST ('blue +cushion')
```

Comment: The `+`, `*` etc... syntax only works IN BOOLEAN MODE.

Comment: what's that? How to use boolean mode.Please give me the answer according to my search results

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410632/mysql-match-against-example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004674/mysql-match-against-in-boolean-mode-returns-nothing-on-middle-word

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `IN BOOLEAN MODE` modifier, because by default MySQL performs a [**natural language search**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).

> With this modifier, certain characters have special meaning at the
>   beginning or end of words in the search string.

Source: [**Boolean Full-Text Searches**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Just rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT a.id as id,a.name as name , a.price as price , a.saleprice as saleprice,
    a.images as images, a.slug as slug,a.hover_name as hover_name,
    MATCH (a.name) AGAINST ('+"blue cushion"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS title_relevance
    FROM gc_products a
    WHERE ( ( ( MATCH (a.name) AGAINST ('+"blue cushion"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) )
    OR (a.sku like '%blue cushion%') )
    AND (a.enabled=1) )
    ORDER BY title_relevance DESC
```

Comment: its not working. It's giving me zero records while I have products with name like "DEAUVILLE red VELVET pleated CUSHION"

Comment: It's not necessary that both the words be together.They can be any where in name but it is necessary that both the words must be there in name. '+' sign means 0 or more while I need at least one time.

Comment: @user3110655 - '+'-sign doesn't mean 0 or more, it means the word **must** be there. If you don't need to have both words together as an exact phrase, but want to have both words present, anyway, omit the " (double quotes) and also add a '+'-sign to the second word. `'+blue +cushion'`

Comment: I tried the same but did not work man. :(. It is giving me results having only suhion e.g "SINTRA purple velvet APPLIQUED CUSHION"