# MySql: Full text ignores pronoun words

Tags: mysql

In Mysql full text search, i've search an phrase "it department" in the indexed field. But it returns the results containing the word department instead of "it department". please guide me to resolve this issue.

Following is the syntax i used,

> select * from employees where match(contents) against("it department")

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931701/mysql-where-match-against

Comment: And read here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html  `Posted by Patrick O'Lone on December 9, 2002` it seems that in your case both words a matched seperate. match `it` and match `department`, thing you have to fix this.

Comment: Simple do `select * from employees where contents like '%it department%'`, if dont get it fixed

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes i've achieve it when i use regex but i have large set of database. Even full text search takes two hours to execute.

Comment: But i'm using phrase query, I even not using any operator to decide the priority and boolean too. This is very strange thing am seeing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql WHERE MATCH AGAINST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931701/mysql-where-match-against)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL FULLTEXT uses a stoplist of common English words. Your favorite word `it` is on the stoplist. The purpose of a stoplist is to keep the index size reasonable.

If you're using MySQL version 5.7+ and InnoDB, you can rig up your own stoplist.

This explains how.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer guys. It is really useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

you should be use 'like' or 'regexp' instead

```
select * from employee where contents regexp'^it department$';
```

or

```
select * from employee where contents like 'it department';
```